# RecycleView does not scroll to the last items

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a List View with Vertical Scroll, its item contains RecyclerView which will scroll Horizontally. 
But when i scroll horizontal, RecyclerView does not allow me to scroll to the last item in the list (the picture below). What's happened with it? Even, i forced it scroll to the last item by setting **linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);** it still does not work, only scroll to half of the 8th item, not the last item in list of 10

Edit: add codes:

list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.phongponix.trackingbodybuilding.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvExerciseList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
       ></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgExcercisePhoto"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp" />

                <TextView android:text="aaa"
                    android:id="@+id/tvExerciseName"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvExcerciseRecords"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_horizontal.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTemp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code for List Adapter:

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvExerciseName);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rvExcerciseRecords);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(trackingPlanHorizontalAdapter);
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (data.size() > 0) {
            ExerciseModel exercise = (ExerciseModel) data.get(i);
            viewHolder.title.setText(exercise.getTitle());
        } else {
            viewHolder.title.setText("No data");
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Code for Recycle Adapter:

```
 public TrackingPlanHorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_horizontal, parent, false);
        return new TrackingPlanHorizontalViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TrackingPlanHorizontalViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(horizontalList.get(position));

    }
```

[image]

Comment: did you try setting margin right to RecyclerView?

Comment: Edit your question with codes related to Vertical RecyclerView and Horizontal RecyclerView so that we can help.

Comment: The ListView is likely capturing the touch event and preventing you from scrolling the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i found your problem,there is problem regarding your **list_item.xml** change your list item with below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imgExcercisePhoto"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExerciseName"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaa" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_panel"
        android:id="@+id/rvExcerciseRecords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's because of my TableLayout.